# Are jexlscript objects thread safe

Tags: jexl

I know that the jexlengine and jexltemplate are thread safe so I can instantiate one instance for use throughout the system. However, are the jexlscript instances created via jexlengine.createscript(...) thread safe ? I googled this and can't find an answer.
I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, JEXL scripts and the interpreter are thread-safe; the same script can be executed concurrently by different threads . However, the objects and methods called through the script must enforce their own thread-safety.

Comment: Found this line in the JEXL documentation: "Once built, the JEXL engine should be stored, shared and reused. It is thread-safe ; so are the scripts during evaluation. "

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/